# How to pass parameters to %simulate cell for Q# in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: q#

I am getting an error when I pass parameters after the %simulate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment passing parameters to operation invoked via `%simulate` is not supported; you'll have to write a wrapper operation which takes no arguments and calls your operation with the parameters you want, and to call `%simulate` on that operation.

That being said, I completely agree that this would be a neat feature! It would probably be trickier to implement it for some kinds of parameters (such as qubits) than the others (such as integers), but it would definitely improve Q# Jupyter Notebooks user experience.  Could you please open an issue at the [iqsharp GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp) to get more visibility on this request?